# QRCode+Perform Respective Actions After Scanning

Tags: iphone, ios, qr-code

In my application i have implemented QR Code Scanner using zbar library.For now i just scan the QRcode and show the code which is read on textview but i want to detect the code type (phone number,email,facebook like page,skype call,etc) and perform the respective action.
Please suggest me some easy method for doing the same..Thanks In Advance:)

Comment: I am not sure how we can do it with zbar API but surely this can be done with ZXing API. I have worked on 2 projects which are having the same things. Let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From zBarSDK you get output with some prefix like TEL:+123456789,URL:www.google.com,SMSTO:+123456789,etc.....
here use switch case with filtering prefix and give the condition like

if prefix is TEL then call directly with UIApplication

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: ouputnumber];
```

same as for URL and also for every output.....

Hope,this  help you..
:)